# What type of Bread Improver should one use for non-yeast bread?

Tags: bread, yeast, flatbread

From what people are telling me, there would be no benefit from using S-500 and similar bread and dough conditioners on an unleavened, non-yeast dough.

What would you recommend for such types of bread/dough?

Thank You.

Comment: What particular benefit do you hope to achieve by using dough conditioners? They're not ordinary used outside an industrial setting.

Comment: @Sneftel I am starting a small bussines on my island and my plans are to make both Pita Bread with Yeast & Flatbread such as Tandoor, Tandoor has NO yeast in it and is very old type of Arabic/Asian bread, its over 1000 years old. My particular benefits would to improve the texture of the Tandoor bread, give it a longer shelf life, etc.....

Comment: @Sneftel I have a compact pita bread machine that will do the entire pita process, so I would also need something that will improve the dough workability in the machine.

Comment: @pumpum_bread, please ask only one question per post. Your title asks about improvers for non-leavened bread. Stick to that question in this post. If you also want to ask about improvers for pita (leavened bread) then you can make a new post to ask about that.

Comment: @ThePhoton I am not asking I was just trying to give an idea. The above questions is just about unleavened bread, only.